# Is it possible to reload a page once with react and react router?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, reload

I need to reload my page when I render certain component using react router. I need this because I need a JavaScript script to load again and detect a certain form tag with a particular id. If I don't reload the page, the script never detects the form's id.  (This script makes some validation on the form).

If I go to the contact component from my home component (root) the script doesn't work (I can send the form with empty fields). But if I go to the contact component from home, and I reload the page, the script starts working.

This is the error I get when home is rendered and the script doesn't detect the form id:

```
form-submission-handler.js:162 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null at HTMLDocument.loaded (form-submission-handler.js:162)
```

And this is what is used to detect the id:

```
function loaded() {
    console.log('contact form submission handler loaded successfully');
   // bind to the submit event of our form
   var form = document.getElementById('gform');
   form.addEventListener("submit", handleFormSubmit, false);
};
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', loaded, false);
```

So, if I reload the page, form-submission-handler script can detect the form.

[Here](https://jfuenmayor96.github.io/EverLeds/) is a page where you can replicate what is happening. Just go to "Contacto" section, it's in the Navbar.

The form submission handler script is inside a script tag before the  tag in my index.html file, where the app is rendered.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to reload page with react and react router. To reload, you would simply provide anchor link to the url with contacts, and when user clicks on that anchor, page with that url would be fetched again from the server (you do have to make sure that your server would respond to that url and return your react app)

However, people generally go to the lengths to **prevent react apps from reloading**, since on reload all state of your react app is lost. Also I can not think of any situation in which I actually **needed to reload** react app, especially not for something as ordinary as form validation and submission. So, while your need to reload might still be justified, there is strong indication that you are trying to use react in some rather strange way, and that your problem might be resolved by getting more used to react and its usual usage patterns.

Comment: Hi. I've already tried that. Instead of using the <Link to="contacto"> in mi navbar, I used <a href="localhost:3000/#/Contacto"> and it doesn't reload the page, appears an alert message saying that if I want to open a 'xdg-open' link. Thank you for your help.

Comment: use urls of form: href="localhost:3000/Contacto" both on your server and react router (no #). But as I said: it looks like you try to fix one broken window on house whose foundations are completely gone and it is about to collapse. Try to fix the cause why you are even thinking about reload

Comment: I could fix the href issue, but what I need is still not happening/working. I believe I will have to port this script to React. Thank you for your help!